# Select a function overload based upon the first argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to create a function `f` that accepts a `Box<T>` as its first argument, and a second argument of type `T` that is optional if (and only if!) `T extends null`.

Here is how one would call `f`:

```
let _ = new Box(null)
let o = new Box({})

f(_, null) // ✅
f(o, {})   // ✅
f(_)       // ✅
f(o)       // ❌ (should not compile)
```

And here is how I have (attempted to) define `f`:

```
class Box<V = any> {
  constructor(public v: V) {}
}

type _ = null
type O = object

function f<V extends _>(b: Box<V>, v?: V): void
function f<V extends O>(b: Box<V>, v: V): void
function f(b: Box, v?: any) {}
```

This seems to work at first glance. But there's a problem! The error for `f(o)` reports the following:

`Argument of type 'Box<{}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Box<null>'.`

When the error I want users of `f` to actually see is:

`Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.`

It seems that TypeScript is preferentially selecting the overload where the second argument is optional. How do I make it select the other overload when `T` does not extend null? Or otherwise achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the error you want if you use a conditional type in a rest parameter to basically change the optionality of the last argument based on `V`:

```
function f<V>(b: Box<V>, ...a: V extends null ? [v?: V]: [v:V]): void
function f(b: Box, v?: any) {}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2APAPANWgXmmAdgTwD5oBvAKGmmHhwgBcAnAV2FvnoAoAHRgIxAEtg0AG4AuaKgCUJAL6k5pWnk4BTaAH1M0HIxAhFytQHkt8HgCsVLUqQBmjHC37VottAXY9xCFKgIAaaAA6ELBxdBVEWhUcABMYHT1oAH5oAG1hZPCAXXEM0VRsyXFheH5YuwcnF1tPbyRAzPFcPGliBRAVWg0tHBUAdzgkdkSQSVJO7vhegaHEdnbxu3Z1QNHpAHoN6EBQcmX4QMWKaC3d5fVpY+PTvdr4S6uT7cAZcmh2CAALeF1Y7XhuqgAW04-E64yAA)

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you :)